Please help ID this bike. What advice can you give me about finding a good home for this Black Bike and/or its components?
Please try to identify this bike. Does it have any collectible value?















Give them all to charity or a local bicycle co-op if that exists. Alternatively put them into some form of recycling system e.g scrapyard.

IMHO it's a beautiful bike. Should you try to sell it, start by cleaning it really thoroughly. Don't expect it to fetch a high price, though.

My guess is that this started out as a French bike based on the derailleurs and the crank set. Then the wheels and the pedals were swapped out. Being French narrows it down to about a half dozen bike makers and dozens of models over a 5 year period - which is to say not really very narrow at all.

A lot of European parts on that bike, Huret and Cinelli.   That doesn't mean a lot, but it likely pre-dates the Shimano rise in the mid 80s.  These brands were available worldwide.
The triple chainset looks interesting with the middle ring being only slightly smaller than the big, but with a diminutive inner/grannie gear.  I'd guess that came from a touring bike and was fitted later.
It has caliper rim brakes, which wouldn't be on a touring bike of the era.
I'd say its a relatively small frame from the photos, and would suit a shorter rider.
This is the first one with pedals fitted, so probably more of a frequent ride than your other two which don't currently have pedals.

As for value we can't do pricing or estimates - those vary too much from place to place, and across time.
You have options for each bike:

Pick the one you like and ride it yourself.  That would be a great thank-you to the former owner.   Also consider family members or the PO's friends/neighbours.
Donate them to a local bike cooperative - that way someone else will get use out of them
Donate to a local non-bike group.  Example, near me is "Menzshed" who do all-sorts of things with donations.
List item on a local auction site with no/low reserve.  The listing will find a value based on what someone is prepared to pay, which is exactly the definition of "worth"
Finally, for broken or useless parts, there is always the scrapyard or recycling stream.  That would be a disappointing end.

Good luck !
